# How to obtain the Week of the month in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, split

My input is this: 2021 W15 (12-Apr) and I am trying to obtain the # of the Week, in this case 15
=split('2021','W',())

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
=substitute(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"W[0-9]+"),"W","")
```

Comment: `=regexextract(A1, "W(\d+)")`.